# creating a block

Tags: blocks

I created my first block in drupal. It basically creates a node create link for the places content type. But someone it doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this.

```
function custom_site_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {  
$blocks = array();
if ($op == "list") {
    // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page

$blocks['create_place'] = array(
    'info' => t('Create a place'),
    'cache' => BLOCK_CACHE_GLOBAL,
);
}
else {

    $form = array();
    $form['#action'] = url('node/add/place');
    $form['create'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create a place'),
    );

}
 return $blocks;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function custom_site_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {  
  $blocks = array();

  switch ($op) {

    case 'list':

      $blocks['create_place']['info'] = t('Create a place');
      $blocks['create_place']['cache'] = BLOCK_CACHE_GLOBAL;

      return $blocks;

    case 'view':

      switch ($delta) {

        case 'create_place':

          $blocks['subject'] = t('My First Block');
          $blocks['content'] = l(t('Create a place'),'node/add/place');

          return $blocks;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

also where I do write a block specific css ? just inside my theme file ?

Comment: You can just add it to any of your theme's css files or add it yourself with `drupal_add_css().`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the menu system to do this. Go to 'admin/structure/menu' and add a menu and a menu item with the link above. This will automatically create a block.

Comment: Does it mean I cannot create menu items by writing a block ?

Comment: You can create links in custom blocks but it would be a wasted effort. Why write custom code in a custom module when Drupal core already has this functionality?

Comment: Actually I know that but i wanna change the way the link appears. How Can I do this ? Do I need to write a view for this ?

Comment: You need to be more precise in what you are asking for. In your description you say, "It basically creates a node create link".  Please either revise the question or mark it as answered. Either way please update the title to more precisely reflect what you are trying to do.